# How do I make my stubbed ajax calls live throughout my karma jasmine test cycle?

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js, karma-jasmine, jasmine-ajax

I have a backbone application where by instantiating one view, a whole chain of ajax calls get called. So if I have MainView.js and I instantiate it `new MainView()`, MainView instantiates IASModel.js which makes a request and returns a promise to MainView. Then, MainView instantiates TestCastModel.js and makes anther ajax call etc... If I were to test MainView.js, I would have to stub all these ajax calls (https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-ajax). Then as my test progress, I would gradually have to programmatically create less of these ajax stubs, because my application is progressing.

How would I just have one file that lives throughout the lifecycle of all my tests? I want to be able to grab any ajax request, have that one file process it (route to appropriate path) and return the stub for that call.

Comment: Which test-runner are you using? Most of them lets you define some sort of init function and that's where you want your stub to be setup.

Comment: I'm using karma runner https://github.com/karma-runner/karma. I'm using that though https://github.com/karma-runner/grunt-karma.

Comment: See if you, in the gruntfile, can add an init-script under *options -> files* and set up the stubbing there. Something like `files: ['test/init.js', 'test/**/*.js']` to ensure it runs before the tests.